# Picking random image from array 60+ choices javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I understand this question has tons of answers already, but I am trying to figure out how to do this in the most efficient way. I have a website that sends an image with a button click to a phone number, but I want to choose between 60 or so photos and manually entering all of these image locations into an array does not seem ideal. 
Here is my js file that performs the email action, this is all hosted on a free hosting service.

```js
// server.js
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
app.use(express.static("public"))

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html") 
  /* this sends the "index.html" file when people go to app.glitch.me/ */
})

app.get("/send", (req, res) => {
// where node app starts
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: process.env.USER,
    pass: process.env.PASS,
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: process.env.USER,
  to: process.env.RECIP,
  subject: "As you requested",
  text: '',
  attachments: [
    {
 /*image location*/
      path: 'https://post.healthline.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2020/02/322868_1100-1100x628.jpg',
    }
  ]
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
}); 

  res.redirect("/sent.html") // after sending the email, redirect back to "index.html" at app.glitch.me/
})
app.listen(3000); //open for traffic
```

Here is my HTMl if its even relevant to my question

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Hello!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style_index.css">

     <a href="/send">click me for snazzy pics</a><!-- script to ping --!>

    <!-- import the webpage's javascript file -->
    <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
  </head>  
  <body>
    <h1>hello</h1>

    <p>
      I made this.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "manually entering all of these image locations into an array does not seem ideal"... of course they'll have to be listed _somewhere_ and having the array in your source code is by far the easiest. Picking a random entry from that array is trivial when you have it.

Comment: I was thinking there might be some way to pick from a folder of images opposed to an array @AKX

Comment: There certainly is, but if all of the images are on a remote host, as you currently seem to have, there's no folder of images to access.

Answer (score 1):

Try first logging all of your images from where they are hosted. If it is not a database you can call upon then you may need to create an array of them manually. Once they are in an object, you can simply use a variable to determine which position in the array that image link should come from. I hope the below helps.

For example:

```
imageChoices = ["https://post.healthline.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2020/02/322868_1100-1100x628.jpg", "https://post.healthline.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2020/02/322868_1100-1100x628.jpg", etc.]

randomIndexChooser = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 1;


var mailOptions = {
  from: process.env.USER,
  to: process.env.RECIP,
  subject: "As you requested",
  text: '',
  attachments: [
    {
 /*image location*/
      path: imageChoices[randomIndexChooser],
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to make an ajax service that calls an api, the api loops through all the files that are in the specified folder and returns the list of file paths. after you get the list from the api, you append them to the wanted array in your javascript code.

I will provide you a sample in asp.net c# , you may be working on another framework, but you can benefit from the idea at least.

here is a function in an api

```cs
[HttpGet]
       public List<string> GetImageFilesPaths()
       {
//getfiles returns all found files' paths in a specified directory
           List<string> imageFilePaths = Directory.GetFiles("folderpath", "*.png", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
       }
```

ajax service that calls the API

```js
  $.ajax({
        url:'hostname/apiname/GetImageFilesPaths'
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){
            //here you append the result which is the list of file path
            //into your wanted array, you can also loop 
            result.forEach((imagePath)=>{
          arrayOfImages.push(imagePath)
          })

        }
    })
```

Comment: alright, I will try to port this over to js. thank you.